# Is there any way to loop randomly through the keys of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that looks something like

```
 for (var key in myObjectArray) {
   [code]
 }
```

I would like to do the same thing except have the order of the output shuffled every time.

Is there any easy way to do it?  I can make a separate array of keys, sort them, and then do a for loop with an index… but that seems like a lot of work and rather inefficient.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: It's already somewhat randomly, as order is not guaranteed in an object.

Comment: @adeneo Not guaranteed, but deterministic nevertheless.

Comment: Pretty sure chrome sorts objects first by integers then lexicographically, but don't quote me

Answer (score 10):

Yes. First, you need an array of keys:

```
var keys;
if( Object.keys) keys = Object.keys(myObjectArray);
else keys = (function(obj) {var k, ret = []; for( k in obj) if( obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) ret.push(k); return ret;})(myObjectArray);
// isn't browser compatibility fun?
```

Next, shuffle your array.

```
keys.sort(function() {return Math.random()-0.5;});
// there are better shuffling algorithms out there. This works, but it's imperfect.
```

Finally, iterate through your array:

```
function doSomething(key) {
    console.log(key+": "+myObjectArray[key]);
}
if( keys.forEach) keys.forEach(doSomething);
else (function() {for( var i=0, l=keys.length; i<l; i++) doSomething(keys[i]);})();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That's pretty much what I was doing already and seemed pretty complicated, knowing how easy it is to sort an array.

Comment: Delete my "thx, me2" if you must, but I really love genius answers like this